# which PHP OAuth library?

Tags: php, oauth

I see a number of PHP OAuth libraries with a quick web search:

- http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth
- http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=512
- http://code.google.com/p/oauth-for-php/
- http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

Which one is the most reliable and easy-to-use?

Comment: Which PHP Server API are you using? What is your target for the OAuth library?

Comment: Which PHP Server API? I don't understand. The target is Google Docs. From what I hear that shouldn't matter much, though. I'm trying to make a small application that presents a list of documents for a Google Docs account.

Comment: The other role would be that you want others Oauth services, so they can authenticate against your service. That's why I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always nice to have choice, but I think you should stick with one of those, probably the [pecl one](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) as it's a compiled one.

Comment: Will you say more about why I should pick that one? Being compiled doesn't necessarily make it more reliable or easy to use.

Comment: It's stable, has recent updates, multiple developers, compiled means often much more stable software and easier to use, faster, more reliable. Compare this offering with the other libs, but decide on your own. No one else can take away your own decision.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give the pecl one a shot, if it seems ok, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.